# How to update AD User's Full name (Not Display Name) via c#

Tags: c#, active-directory

Existing answers confuse "Full name" with Display name. I can update AD user properties via c# (e.g.  I can update  First name, Last name, Display name) but not "Full name"

To see Full name search for a user in AD and in results right click on name and select Rename and "Full name" field is displayed along with name surname and display name

**"Full name" is different from Display name (or name/surname or combinations) and can have different value.** By default Full name is set to username and I need to change it to be same as display name.

Does anyone know how to update 'Full name' value using c#? Thanks

Comment: There is a similar question with helpful information:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408665/updating-name-field-on-userprincipal

Comment: [There is a similar question with good responses:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408665/updating-name-field-on-userprincipal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually rename method that changes the full name, (or the name shown in results when queried via manual AD search.

```
string myNewValue = "mySurname, myFirstName".Replace(",", "\\,"); //escape comma
userDirectoryEntry.Rename("CN=" + myNewValue);
userDirectoryEntry.CommitChanges();
```